# Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop, callstack

I am trying to wait for an element to be created, so what I did was loop (well technically caused an infinite loop somehow) until that element exists. I don't have control over this or else of course I'd place my JS below the JS that creates the element.

In my IIFE I have

```
awe = function(opts){
    if(d.getElementsByClassName('sceditor-container')[0]){
     return new AWE(opts);
     }else return editor(opts);
};
```

I've tried many different methods, such as not returning and just doing `awe(opts)` and `editor(opts)` I write editor because in my IIFE I return `(window.editor = awe)` Is there a better methodology behind waiting for an element. I already have my `awe/editor` wrapped in a dom ready function like so

```
 $(function(){
   var textEditor = editor({
                    //options
                });
       textEditor.add();
 });
```

Tried this as well guys

```
awe = function(opts){
    if(!d.getElementsByClassName('sceditor-container')[0]){
       interval=setInterval(awe(opts),100);
     }else{
      clearInterval(interval);
      return new AWE(opts);
     }
};
```

**note** also I have tried using this with a timeout to give it a break

**UPDATED**
Decided to add a `ready` function to the AWE object

```
ready:function(cb){
    var target = document.querySelector('#textarea_content');
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
          var added = mutation.addedNodes;
          for(var i = 0;i<added.length;i++){
            if((/sceditor-container/g).test(added[i].className)){
              cb();
            }
          }
           observer.disconnect();
        });    
    });
    var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
    // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
    observer.observe(target, config);
  }
```

callback is not running correctly.

Comment: javascript is single threaded. You may want to solve this creating your loops with setInterval

Comment: At least use an interval, don't just create an endless loop. There are also mutation observers.

Comment: updated. I added an interval.

Comment: You are calling `awe` in your `setInterval` which will schedule another interval which will schedule another interval which will schedule another interval which will schedule another interval which will schedule another interval .. you get the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is an event driven language. Using `setInterval` *can* work. But there are event driven solutions as well:

1. Use events from awe. I don't have an experience with awe but maybe there is a `load` or `ready` event you can listen to.
2. MutationObservers. This is a native API (supported by all modern browsers). It allows you to listen to changes to the DOM. Look for your node in the change list.

Comment: AWE is my library. I am using this as a middle man for different libraries but core library is SCEditor. And I'll take a peak at the MutationObservers.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the MO. I added a ready function like you stated. But i am still having problems for some reason. Please see update.

Comment: `target` is null. You're looking for the signature (class name) of a node that doesn't exist yet. You must observe the parent node and look for the signature of the child node in the mutation list.

Comment: Yes finally figured that out, was about to come back and tell you.

Comment: Ok so I fixed that bug, but now the callback won't run :/

Answer (score 1):

[MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) is a good solution if you're targeting modern browsers (>= IE 11).

Here's an example:

```
var parentDiv = document.createElement('div')

var observer = new MutationObserver(function (event) {
    console.log("childList changed");
    console.dir(event);
});

observer.observe(parentDiv, {
    childList: true
});

parentDiv.appendChild(document.createElement('div'))
```

Otherwise you can fall back to using setInterval

Comment: Great Answer, can you take a look at my update, I've changed AWE to an object and added a ready property.